# springboot Upgrade from 2.3.5.RELEASE to 2.4.1- ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, spring-cloud

I am trying to upgrade my kotlin - gradle project from springboot version 2.3.5.RELEASE to 2.4.1. Looks like there is version mismatch between springboot-2.4.1 and sping-cloud-Hoxton.SR9.

**build.gradle.kts snippet**

```
    plugins {
        id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.1"
        id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
    
        kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.10"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.4.10"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.4.10"

    idea
    }
    
    group = "com.xxx"
    version = ""
    java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    extra["springCloudVersion"] = "Hoxton.SR9"
    
    val resilience4jVersion = "1.3.1"
    val queryDslVersion = "4.4.0"
    val springCloudVersion = "Hoxton.SR9"
    val cucumberVersion = "6.7.0"
    val camundaVersion = "7.14.0"
    var jacocoVersion = "0.8.5"

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:$springCloudVersion")
    }
}


dependencies {

    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign")
    implementation("org.javers:javers-core:5.12.0")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.1")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.1")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.1")


    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas")
    // Aop dependency
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5")

    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.3")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.3")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration")
    implementation("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka")
    implementation("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:3.3.0.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-tx")

    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    implementation("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.6.0")

    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-kotlin:1.4.3")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.4.3")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-hateoas:1.4.3")
}
```

When I run the springboot application, I get following exception. The application was working properly before upgrading to the newer version.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@16f65612]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:586) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:244) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:767) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:572) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:212) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:362) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.xxxx.MyApplicationKt.main(MyApplication.kt:22) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@16f65612]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:417) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:388) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:335) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Please help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 67):

Hoxton is not compatible with Spring Boot 2.4 use 2020.0.0

Comment: What do you mean by *Spring Boot 2.4 use 2020.0.0*?

Comment: `val springCloudVersion = "2020.0.1"`

Answer (score 28):

There is an official version of spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap available now, adding this solved the problem for me.

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
>   <version>3.0.1</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Answer (score 10):

The resolution below helped me when updating to Spring Boot v2.5.6 (latest version as of 21 Oct, 2021 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.5.6 for more info):

I have updated spring cloud version in pom.xml

```
<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
```

Earlier I was using below version with Spring Boot < v2.3.0

```
<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
```

Comment: I've solved like this  used eureka-client.version=3.0.2 and spring-cloud.version=2020.0.4 spring.boot.version 2.5.6

Comment: from [basic links] https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud    
Table 1. Release train Spring Boot compatibility  
*Release Train                    Boot Version
*2021.0.x aka Jubilee         2.6.x
*2020.0.x aka Ilford           2.4.x, 2.5.x (Starting with 2020.0.3)
*Hoxton                             2.2.x, 2.3.x (Starting with SR5)
*Greenwich                        2.1.x
*Finchley 2.0.x
*Edgware 1.5.x
*Dalston 1.5.x

Spring Cloud Dalston, Edgware, Finchley, and Greenwich have all reached end of life status and are no longer supported.

Answer (score 6):

According to https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud, you can try below.

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
         <version>2020.0.4</version>
         <type>pom</type>
         <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding a dependency management import with mavenBom fixed it for me

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:Hoxton.SR10"
    }
}
```

Comment: working stuff, thanks

Answer (score 5):

There is a release train spring boot compatibility table available on spring official Page - [Link](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud)

Which clearly outlines which version of Spring Cloud maps to which version of Spring Boot.

For Spring Boot Version 2.4.x, 2.5.x  Spring Cloud **2020.0.x aka Ilford**

Check out the Spring Cloud 2020.0 Release Notes for any known issues - [Link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes)

Answer (score 4):

Adding following version of `neflix-eureka-client` version resolved this issue for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This comment helped me resolve my issue. In particular, removing an unused dependency on org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius:2.2.7.RELEASE fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

@spencergibb was near correct, but still I was getting same error. Along with @spencergibb's answer, I have added **spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap** dependency to make run it successfully.

```
extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2020.0.0"
val springCloudVersion = "2020.0.0"

implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap")
```

I followed this link to make it work

https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/book-update-2.4.0/

Comment: I´m running into this issue without using Spring Cloud at all. Are those dependencies now mandatory?

Comment: I get: "Could not find org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:2020.0.0"

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I updated Springboot from 2.3.12.RELEASE to 2.5.*

After a lot of head breaking, I figured out that there is a transitive dependency spring-cloud-starter:2.0.0.RELEASE which is not compatible with Spring 2.4 and above.

Finally, it is fixed by updating Springboot version to 2.5.12 and overriden existing spring-cloud-starter version to 3.0.5

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.12</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my pom worked for me as `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata` has depreceated from spring 2.2.0

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```