# upgrading spring boot to 2.4.1

Tags: java, spring

I need to upgrade my spring boot to 2.4.1 from 2.3.7.RELEASE.
when I update my pom file, I get error in spring-security-oauth2 dependency (version 2.4.1.RELEASE).
before I've upgraded my spring version, spring-security-oauth2 2.4.1.RELEASE, worked fine with springboot 2.3.7.RELEASE

my pom file dependency:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

this is my exception when I try to run my app-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:244) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:767) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:572) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:203) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:114) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:71) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at
```

[image]

how can I update my springboot version without having trouble with this dependency?

Comment: You are talking about upgrading Spring Boot than why are you moving `spring-security-oauth` to a spring boot version?

Comment: you mean why spring-security-oauth version is 2.4.1.RELEASE?

thats the original version I had in my project. before I've upgraded to 2.4.1, the previous springboot version was 2.3.7.RELEASE, and spring-security-oauth 2.4.1.RELEASE worked fine

Comment: You haven't shown us all your dependencies, and now when I look closely at your stacktrace the error comes from a Spring Cloud dependency. Spring Cloud versions are tied to a Spring Boot version. If you upgrade Spring Boot you also need to upgrade the Spring Cloud versions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with incompatibility between your spring cloud and spring boot version, please upgrade your spring cloud version to be compatible with spring boot 2.4.x.

Reference : [springboot Upgrade from 2.3.5.RELEASE to 2.4.1- ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65488101/springboot-upgrade-from-2-3-5-release-to-2-4-1-classnotfoundexception-org-spri)