# After upgrading Spring Boot to 2.7.7 getting ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

In my Kotlin Maven project am trying to upgrade Spring Boot from 2.3.12.RELEASE to 2.7.7 but when I try to build the project, I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@75b84c92]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:417)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:388)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
        ... 104 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2729)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2003)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467)
        ... 110 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 114 common frames omitted
```

I tried to find the solution on the existing topic [springboot Upgrade from 2.3.5.RELEASE to 2.4.1- ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65488101/springboot-upgrade-from-2-3-5-release-to-2-4-1-classnotfoundexception-org-spri) but I actually don't have dependency for spring-cloud-dependencies. What I have in my pom.xml that is related to spring cloud is this:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there an easy way to avoid these exceptions?

I read about Spring Cloud Security reaching end of life but I am not sure how to do the migration.

I tried adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2021.0.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

but it didn't help.

Here is my full pom.xml (some company data removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <description>
        ...
    </description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.8.0</kotlin.version>
        <kotlinx-coroutines.version>1.6.4</kotlinx-coroutines.version>
        <start-class>...</start-class>

        <micrometer.version>1.10.3</micrometer.version>

        <jjwt.version>0.11.5</jjwt.version>
        <karate.version>0.9.6</karate.version>
        <hibernate-types.version>2.21.1</hibernate-types.version>

        <junit-jupiter.version>5.9.2</junit-jupiter.version>
        <mockito.project.version>3.12.4</mockito.project.version>

        <spring-security.version>5.3.1.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <cucumber-reporting.version>5.7.4</cucumber-reporting.version>
        <woodstox-core.version>6.4.0</woodstox-core.version>
        <jackson-dataformat-xml.version>2.11.4</jackson-dataformat-xml.version>
        <trimou.version>2.5.1.Final</trimou.version>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <connection>...</connection>
        <url>...</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>...</id>
            <name>...</name>
            <url>...</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>...</id>
            <name>...</name>
            <url>...</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Prometheus monitoring endpoint -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
            <version>${micrometer.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <version>${micrometer.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Kotlin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-core</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlinx-coroutines.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- XML, Atom/RSS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-dataformat-xml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
            <version>${woodstox-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON handling-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.project.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.project.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Karate Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
            <version>${karate.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${karate.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber-reporting.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Template Engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.trimou</groupId>
            <artifactId>trimou-core</artifactId>
            <version>${trimou.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>...</id>
            <name>Public-Mirror</name>
            <url>...</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>...</id>
            <name>Public-Mirror</name>
            <url>...</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>

        <!-- Config for the Karate testing framework -->
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/kotlin</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.kt</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0-r1585899</version>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                        <plugin>all-open</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <pluginOptions>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Entity</option>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Embeddable</option>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass</option>
                    </pluginOptions>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>skip-deploy-if-non-master-branch</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>env.GIT_BRANCH</name>
                    <value>!master</value>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>integrationtest</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!--
                    Wait for the Spring Boot app to be ready.
                    -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.slem1</groupId>
                        <artifactId>await-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>wait-for-application-startup</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>Await</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <poll>
                                <attempts>10</attempts>
                                <sleep>3000</sleep>
                            </poll>
                            <httpConnections>
                                <httpConnection>
                                    <url>http://localhost:18090</url>
                                    <statusCode>200</statusCode>
                                </httpConnection>
                            </httpConnections>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: The fact that you get this error indicates you have incompatible versions of libraries. Generally this comes from trying to outsmart the `spring-boot-starter` dependency management and/or managing individual dependencies yourself. Please add your dependencies (your full `pom.xml` to the question).

Comment: Edited the question, added full pom.xml

Comment: `spring-cloud-starter-oauth2` version 2.2.5 is bound to Spring Boot 2.3 so this won't work with 2.7. So either don't upgrade or stop using that dependency.

Comment: Is there something I can use instead of this dependency?

Comment: That is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59273338/what-is-the-replacement-for-the-deprecated-authorizationserver-in-spring-securit